# Unix dir sort directories by date time and select all directories leaving first n directories

Tags: sorting, unix, directory

I have a directory which has N number of sub directories. Now, I need to sort them by last modified date and time and then I need to select all directories leaving first n number of directories.

I did `dir -td */`  to sort. I tried `dir -td */ | head -n 5` Which is actually not working. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
find -type d -exec ls -td1 {} \; | tail -n +15
```

Using the find and tail command you can able to achieve this. For the tail command the + sign is needed. So, only it skips the first nth directories.